# In C# .NET, how can I read a textfile with an ascii-based proprietary encoding

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, binaryfiles

My proprietary text encoding uses all 256 byte values with the lower 128 being mostly the same as ascii (the important stuff i.e. control characters, spaces, newlines are all exactly the same). I want to be able to read this file as bytes in C# .NET and still maintain the ability to read it line by line and do regex searches on it. What is the best way to do this in C# .NET?

I realize that if my encoding only used the first 128 byte values this would be simple. I just don't want the higher characters to get accidentally converted to unicode values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to implement your own subclass of `Encoding`. It's reasonably straightforward to do this, and then you can pass it to the `StreamReader` constructor (or `File.OpenText` etc.

If you look at the [code I wrote (many years ago) to handle EBCDIC](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/ebcdic/), you should be able to use that as a reasonable starting point.

The overlap with ASCII seems pretty much irrelevant to this, by the way.

> I just don't want the higher characters to get accidentally converted to unicode values.

Any time you convert *any* binary data into text, you're converting to Unicode values. That's how text in .NET is defined.

Comment: Would a subclass of `Encoding` be able to dynamically change the encoding system? Because I actually have multiple encodings I need to switch between, some of which are not known at compile time.

Comment: @Matt: Would the whole of a particular stream be in one encoding though? If so, I'd write separate subclasses, and choose one dynamically, but use the same one throughout.

Comment: Like I said, some of them might not be known at compile time.

Comment: @Matt: I didn't say you had to know which one at compile time. You can choose one dynamically at execution time, but still use the same one to read the whole of the data. `Encoding encoding = ChooseEncoding(...); var reader = File.OpenText(file, encoding)...`

Comment: I mean some of the encodings themselves might not be known. I'm not only talking about which ones to use.

Comment: @Matt: Might not be known at all? You haven't given any indication about how any decision would be made, which makes it very hard to give any suggestions of how you might want to implement it. You could easily write an encoding subclass which simply took an array of 256 characters to represent the mapping from corresponding byte to char...

Comment: Basically, I need to be able to add more different encodings at run time. And I don't know if you can create the subclasses dynamically at run time but that's not something I want to do anyway.

Comment: @Matt: See my previous comment - you can create a single subclass which can cope with any arbitrary single byte mapping, then create different instances whenever you need to.

Comment: Ok, that answers my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can read file in the strem reader as follows:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Details.txt", ASCIIEncoding.ASCII);
```

Comment: you can replace the path "C:\\Details.txt" with your file path

Comment: No, that would only cope if the file were *actually* ASCII. It's not. (Also, prefer `Encoding.ASCII` over `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII`.)